# Editor template is not rendering?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have ICollection of Flying Cards in my model of User.cs.

```
public virtual ICollection<FrequentFlyerCard> FrequentFlyerCards { get; set; }
```

In my User.cshtml view (which is binded strong typed to User model) I have

```
Frequent Flyer Cards: @Html.EditorFor(m => m.FrequentFlyerCards)
```

I've created EditorTemplates folder in Shared folder. Then, I've created FrequentFlyerCard.cshtml in that EditorTemplates folder. My view:

```
@model tramp.Models.FrequentFlyerCard

<div>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Airline, new { placeholder = "Airline"})    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CardNumber, new { placeholder = "Card Number"})
</div>
<div> 
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Airline, new { placeholder = "Airline"})    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CardNumber, new { placeholder = "Card Number"})
</div>
```

This template is simply not rendering. What is the problem?

Comment: What error you are getting? No yellow pages?

Comment: I'm getting no error. It simply does not render

Comment: @Flipper, are you sure the collection is not empty?

Comment: I've checked, it's not empty. I'll try to exit visual studio and create a new one once more.

Comment: Can u add ur action method code to ur question?

Answer (score 0):

You pass in a collection, while your template is for a single FrequentFlyerCard object.